# How to properly execute a linked server stored procedure from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to execute an stored procedure located in a linked server database. Currently, I'm using this in SSMS:

```
INSERT INTO myTable
    EXEC [LINKEDSERVER\LINKED].[Data_Base_Name].[Store].usp_GetInfo 1, 1, NULL, 'H'
```

This will insert into my Local DB the result data from the Stored procedure located in `LINKEDSERVER\LINKED.`

I want to be able to do this with a command from C#, is there a proper way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried executing that command in c#???

Comment: All SQL is executed on the server irrespective of where it comes from so you don't have to do anything special (aside from setting permissions)

Comment: @SeanLange I was looking for examples executing SP in C# and they specify `CommandType.StoredProcedure` do I have to do it?

Comment: The default CommandType is Text which is what you want here I guess. I would actually make a local procedure that does your logic instead. Keep in mind that the code you posted is not the same thing as executing a procedure. You are executing a procedure as part of an insert statement.

Comment: @SeanLange so, I just executed the command like a normal `INSERT` and it worked. I thought it will be more complicated. Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could execute SP from DataContext:

```cs
using (DataContext ctx = DataContext())
{
    int result = ctx.SP_ProcedureName("1", "2", "3");
}
```

But first you have to add it to DataContext Diagram from your database as you add tables but from "Stored Procedures" folder.

that is more defensive and neat solution. but if you prefer to use raw command line at least use parameterized query for it like this example :

```
string sqlText = "SELECT columnName FROM Test_Attachments WHERE Project_Id =@PID1 AND [Directory] = @Directory";

 SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlText, SqlConnection);
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID1", 12);
 myCommand.Parameters.AddwithValue("@Directory", "testPath");
```

It is way for avoiding SQL injection to your code.
Also you could use finally block for close connection :

```
    finally
    {
        command.Connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, this really helped me, I wasn't thinking in the SQL injection. You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help. Oleg thanks for your suggestion as well. What I did was this:

```
qSQL = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " EXEC [LINKEDSERVER\\LINKED].[Data_Base_Name]." + spName;
using (SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
            try
            {
                    command = new SqlCommand();
                    command.Connection = _connection;
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    command.CommandText = _qSQL;
                    command.CommandTimeout = 300; //Because it takes long
                    SqlTransaction transaction;
                    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                    try
                    {
                        command.Transaction = _transaction;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        transaction.Commit();
                        Debug.WriteLine("Done");
                    }
                    catch (SqlException e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Exception [{0}:{1}]", e.Number, e.Message);
                        transaction.Rollback();
                    }
            //close connection
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                    Debug.WriteLine("exception error number: " + e.Number + ": " + e.Message);
                }
            }
}
```

If you have any suggestions to improve this let me know.

Comment: You could use Parameterized Query in SQL command instead direct string command. I have added it to my post